# MySQL join 2 tables (INNER JOIN ?)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join up a two tables Where table category has a column category.parent_id (this is what permites to distinguise between category and subcategory)

```
SELECT c.category_ID
     , c.category_name
     , c.is_active
     , p.name
     , p.cost
     , p.image
     , p.image_link
  FROM category c
  JOIN products p
    ON p.category_ID = c.category_ID
   AND c.category_ID = '$sql_category_id'
```

In $sql_category_id = 29; there are only more (sub)categories and query should return columns

```
 category`.`category_ID`, `category`.`category_name`, `category`.`is_active`
```

the results from column category.category_ID from query $sql_category_id = 29 should be 30, 31, 32

And in $sql_category_id = 30 (or 31 and 32) it should return products elements only cause there are no subcategories.

The thing is, it returns product details (when id = 30,31,32), but when it should list subcategories details it doesn't (id=29)

As asked, I join an example table:

```
table product
product_id | category_id | name                         | cost
         1 |          28 | Aloe Vera Cream              | 5.97
         2 |          30 | Macadamia 100ml Base Oil     | 6.35
         3 |          30 | Hazelnut 100ml Base Oil      | 6.00
         4 |          31 | Clear Skin 100ml Massage Oil | 4.5

table category
 category_id | category_name               | is_active | parent_id
          11 | Aromatherapy                |         1 |         2
          28 | Lotions and Potions         |         1 |        11
          29 | Massage and Base Oils       |         1 |        11
          30 | 100ml Base Oils             |         1 |        29
          31 | 100ml Massage and Bath Oils |         1 |        29
```

if i want to list category '29' it should return 'category_name's '100ml Base Oils' and '100ml Massage and Bath Oils';
listing category '30' it should return 'product_id' '2'(Macadamia 100ml Base Oil ) and '3'('Hazelnut 100ml Base Oil ')
and there is also the case that we have this:

```
table product
product_id | category_id | name            | cost
         5 |          29 | Example Product | 1.21
```

in this case it should have 3 results that are:

```
result 1: '100ml Base Oils'
result 2: '100ml Massage and Bath Oils'
result 3: 'product_id 5' 'Example Product'
```

The current query it works for product listenings:
http://marques.byethost3.com/product.php?cat_id=30 

Not for categories listenings:
http://marques.byethost3.com/product.php?cat_id=29

Comment: Could you please put 2 table schema here ? so we can understand better way

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query